# powershell pull variable from inf file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

```
$OEM = "N/A"
$data = (get-content C:\Windows\INF\OEM27.inf | select-string "10.18.10.4358")
if ($data -eq "DriverVer=12/21/2015,10.18.10.4358"){
$OEM = $true}
else {$OEM = $false}
echo $data
echo $OEM
```

So I'm trying to test this small code out before adding it to my larger script. However $OEM keeps coming up a False even though $data comes back as DriverVer=12/21/2015,10.18.10.4358. Not sure what I'm over looking but it is pretty late at night. Any help would be appreciated. ^^"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object returned by `Select-String` isn't a string. It is a `MatchInfo`:

```
C:\> $data | Get-Member


   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

Name         MemberType Definition
----         ---------- ----------
Equals       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode  Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType      Method     type GetType()
RelativePath Method     string RelativePath(string directory)
ToString     Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string directory)
Context      Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext Context {get;set;}
Filename     Property   string Filename {get;}
IgnoreCase   Property   bool IgnoreCase {get;set;}
Line         Property   string Line {get;set;}
LineNumber   Property   int LineNumber {get;set;}
Matches      Property   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[] Matches {get;set;}
Path         Property   string Path {get;set;}
Pattern      Property   string Pattern {get;set;}
```

You can get to the line it matches on with the `Line` property. So change your code to this:

```
if ($data.Line -eq "DriverVer=12/21/2015,10.18.10.4358")
```

However, I don't think that is very robust code because INI files can have spaces around the "=". This would be better:

```
if ($data.Line -match "DriverVer\s*=\s*12/21/2015,10.18.10.4358")
```

I think your code is a bit over complicated. You could replace the whole thing with this:

```
$OEM = [bool](Select-String "DriverVer\s*=\s*12/21/2015,10.18.10.4358" C:\Windows\INF\OEM27.inf)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, that seemed to work. I'm still a little new to powershell with all the commands you can use. I do tend to make stuff complicated. Long story short HP drivers prevent you from installing Intel drivers by running off the OEM inf. Easy way around this is just to move the corresponding inf out of the folder and it lets you install the Intel driver remotely. Easiest way to fix this when you have 4,000 network computers. lol.